# How do you set YII Bootstrap to only have one fixed size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I know this kind of defeats the purpose of bootstrap, but for various (temporary) reasons I need to set the total width to 1000px, no matter what. The default sizes are imported in responsive.less:

```
@import "responsive-1200px-min.less";
@import "responsive-768px-979px.less";
@import "responsive-767px-max.less";
```

I want to basically exclude  responsive-768px-979px.less and responsive-767px-max.less, and only use: responsive-1200px-min.less, but instead of the width being 1200, I want it set to 1000px. Or more specifically, 1015.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to delete the sections of your `bootstrap-responsive.css` that contain the media queries for 767-979 and 767 max (or re-compile the less file and exclude the imports you do not want).

After this you will want to go through the `bootstrap-responsive.css` and make the 1200px media query as the default (remove the media surrounding tag) and change 1200px and associated values to be 5/6ths the size to create your custom 1000px based design. By doing this you should have a 1000px wide layout.

**Alternative 1**

You could simply not include the responsive counterpart and stick with the fixed 940px wide body. (this isn't 1000px wide, but is very close).

**Issues**

I am guessing bootstrap chose the specific responsive sizes and fixed sizes (when not using the `bootstrap-responsive.css`) with good reasons and changing them is not a good idea.